# SQL - Unable to find partially matching data in two columns

Tags: sql, case, sql-like

I've never posted before, I've usually been able to find my answer, so please bear with me if I exclude anything or format incorrectly.  Here is my issue:

I have two columns that include similar data, for example:

```
Column1            Column2
BASKETBALL         BasketBall-CAVS
BASEBALL REDS      Baseball-SPORTS
```

I am not searching for a specific word, just any word that is found in both columns should populate a "no" under a third column.  So both of the above records should return a NO.  I attempted this:

```
CASE
WHEN Column1 NOT LIKE 
CONCAT('%',Column2,'%') THEN 'Yes' 
ELSE 'No'
END AS Needs_Updated;
```

For some reason, only the first record pictured above returns a "No" in the "Needs_Updated" column.  The second record returns a "Yes" (which isn't correct, two words match in that column).  The only difference in the second record is there is multiple words in column 1.  Can anyone help me out?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "word".  Word-based text analysis is not usually best done in SQL.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Your code is taking the complete COLUMN2 (and not each word separately) when comparing to search within COLUMN1.

The sample data you gave would never return Yes. Neither column contains the other column. Are you certain the data you pasted here is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with regular expressions.  Not all databases support them, so this is tricky with those databases.

Using MySQL syntax:

```
select t.*,
       (case when column2 regexp replace(column1, ' ', '|') then 'no' else 'yes' end) as needs_updated
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Charindex

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(Column2,Column1) > 0 ) THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES'  AS Needs_Updated


CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ])
```

start_location is optional

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql